# ASP.NET MVC : How does my action result find the selected entry in a dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist that I populate with some stuff:

**In my controller**

```
ViewData["SourceModelList"] = new SelectList(_modelService.GetAllModels(), "Id", "Description");
```

**in my view**

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Compare", "Home")) {  %>
    <p>
        <%=Html.DropDownList("SourceModelList")%>
    </p>
    <p>            
        <input type="submit" value="Compare" />
    </p>
<% } %>
```

And this renders lovely.  Now when I post back to my 'compare' action, how do I find out which item was selected in the drop down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name "SourceModelList" should correspond with the name of a field in your ViewModel, so that the binder has something to bind the value of the dropdown to.

Alternatively, you can pluck the value out of the `FormCollection` object, if your view is not strongly-typed.

The **[NerdDinner Tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm)** goes into this process in greater detail:

**NerdDinner Step 5: Create, Update, Delete Form Scenarios**
http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part5.htm

Comment: Thanks Robert.  All the replies were correct (+1) but your link helped me to understand a few other things. Ta.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the regular methods for getting items from a form in ASP.NET MVC: FormCollection, Request object, binding to a specific model or having an action which takes a `string SourceModelList` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["SourceModelList"]);
```

Or by ModelBinders just making sure that your model have a property

```
public int SourceModelList {get; set;}
```

And the ModelBinder will get it for you.

Or, but less likely:

```
public ActionResult Name(FormCollection f, int SourceModelList)
```